# Несоответствие кода страницы в Chrome и самой страницы

Tags: html, python, html5, веб-программирование, selenium

Пытаюсь сделать парсер сайта SoundCloud на python. При попытке получить код страницы, что через requests, что через Selenium html-код страницы выдается некорректным. Попробовал просмотреть код в Хроме, заметил странность: при выборе опции "просмотреть код" если скопировать результат и открыть, страница не соответствует оригиналу. При выборе "просмотреть код элемента" все корректно. В чем дело?

Оригинал страницы

[image: оригинал страницы]

если открываю "код страницы", копирую и снова открываю в браузере

[image: повторное открытие]

Ну, и если открывать код, полученный из requests или через selenium то же самое. Помогите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

Comment: Ничего не понял. У меня через `requests` эта страница отлично открывается со всеми данными

Comment: Это странно, у меня не хочет ни в какую.Можно посмотреть ваш код?

Comment: requests.get(ссылка).text да и всё, ничего особенного не делал

Answer (score 2):

Вы и реквестом и селениумом переходите по "битой" ссылке, вот СаундКлауд и не находит нужной вам страницы. И про это же и написано в сохранённой вами странице))))) Блинский)))))

Тому и подтверждение комментарий andreymal'а